# How to avoid / fix ScriptException error in HTMLUnit?

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I'm trying to access a website on my router so I can automatically control a fish tank. When I try to connect to the website using HTML Unit it gives me an error:

```
Nov 24, 2019 7:46:15 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener scriptException
SEVERE: Error during JavaScript execution
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[108] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[ReferenceError] sourceName=[script in http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht from (76, 32) to (120, 10)] message=[ReferenceError: "nsys_translator" is not defined. (script in http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht from (76, 32) to (120, 10)#108)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "nsys_translator" is not defined. (script in http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht from (76, 32) to (120, 10)#108)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:883)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:812)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:784)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2542)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2535)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:171)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.lambda$executeEventHandlersIfNeeded$0(HtmlPage.java:1248)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1248)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:249)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:541)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:400)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:317)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:469)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:450)
    at AlkOutput.main(AlkOutput.java:43)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "nsys_translator" is not defined. (script in http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht from (76, 32) to (120, 10)#108)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4334)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4312)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:4406)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.nameOrFunction(ScriptRuntime.java:2009)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1948)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1752)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1010)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:424)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:322)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3628)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:805)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:868)
    ... 22 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "nsys_translator" is not defined. (script in http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht from (76, 32) to (120, 10)#108)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4334)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4312)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:4406)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.nameOrFunction(ScriptRuntime.java:2009)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1948)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1752)
    at script(script in http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht from (76, 32) to (120, 10):108)
    at script(script in http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht from (-1, -1) to (-1, -1))
    at script(script in http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht from (-1, -1) to (-1, -1))
    at script(script in http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht from (-1, -1) to (-1, -1))
    at script(script in http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht from (-1, -1) to (-1, -1))
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1010)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:424)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:322)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3628)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:805)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:868)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:812)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:784)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2542)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2535)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:171)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.lambda$executeEventHandlersIfNeeded$0(HtmlPage.java:1248)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1248)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:249)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:541)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:400)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:317)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:469)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:450)
    at AlkOutput.main(AlkOutput.java:43)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
  function () {
      document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", arguments.callee, false);
      T.ready();
  }
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

I don't know how to bypass this error so I can access the website. I have tried using the command `WebClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);` to ignore the error but that doesn't seem to fix the issue. I also tried switching the `BrowserVersion` but that didn't help either. Maybe the issue is something with the website. I don't have access to changing the code on the website. Here is my code.

```
public class AlkOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {

        DefaultCredentialsProvider cred = new DefaultCredentialsProvider();
        cred.addCredentials(username, password); //I didn't include real username / password for privacy

        WebClient web = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER);

        web.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        web.setCredentialsProvider(cred);

        HtmlPage page = web.getPage("http://24.92.140.58:80/outsetup.sht"); //error is on this line

        web.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a question about your code, remember to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

Can you please check if the same error occures with a real browser.

Setting WebClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); still reports the error but continues to process the js in the page (as browsers do).

Why do you think it does not work - do you get the expected page?

Comment: The error still seems to occur when I checked the website in chrome. I've read that real browsers can ignore these errors and still work but HTML Unit has a harder time ignoring these errors. When I load up the page on a real browser the page works fine. My goal was to input commands into a text box on the website and that works with a real browser. I wanted to do it on a headless browser to minimize load.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the default behaviour of HtmlUnit with Java Script errors has always been a mess, for the expectation to find a single page in the internet without error when including tons of script libraries, is quite small. Then, treating any error with an exception, essentially decreases the acceptance of HTMLunit.

For me the common solution has been:

```
WebClient cl =  = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX); // or similair

cl.setCssErrorHandler(...);
cl.setIncorrectnessListener(...);
cl.setJavaScriptErrorListener(...);
cl.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

where `...` is to be replaced with **empty** implementations of dedicated interfaces.